# Confused about adding record into database using Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, orm

i'm very new at hibernate and have some confused . I have a table Account(Id,Username,Password,email_id) which is empty  have one-one relationship with table Email(id,email) which have few record and have code below

my Account class

```
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "Username")
    @Size(max = 3)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "Password")
    private String password;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "email_id")
    Email email;
//getter setter constructor
```

my Email class

```
@Table(name = "email")
public class Email {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "email")
    private Account account;
//getter setter constructor
```

and my function to get save entity Account

```
  @Autowired
    SessionFactory SessionFactory;

public void addAccountDAO(Account account) {

        Session session = SessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

        try {
/// way 1
            account.setEmail(session.getReference(Email.class, 1));
// way 2
//            Email email = new Email();
//            email.setId(1);
//            account.setEmail(email);
            session.save(account);
            t.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            t.rollback();

        } finally {

            session.close();
        }

    }
```

My problems is when i apply the way 2 to setEmail and insert into table account. It not only insert data to account but also update entity like output of hibernate right there

```
Hibernate: insert into account (email_id, Password, Username) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update email set email=? where id=?
```

But when use way 2 instead , it just insert only to account without update email.

```
Hibernate: insert into account (email_id, Password, Username) values (?, ?, ?)
```

I'm very confused between 2 way cause it same have a same primary key but result in different query of hibernate. Please shed the light for me on this problem, thank guys very much